# SSL Error while setting connection through rest-client

Tags: java, post, ssl-certificate, rest-client

I am developing a JAVA 1.8v RestClient which is supposed to call a Rest API exposed by a external application. Below is snippet of my code for reference:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;


public class RestClientJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String request = "JSON Request in string format";
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:port/restService/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //logger.info("Auth Header: "+ authHeader); 
            
            String password = "USERNAME"+":"+"PASSWORD";
            
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(password.getBytes())));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            
            String input = request;
//          HostnameVerifier bypass = new HostnameVerifier();
//          bypass.ignoreCertificates();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

         }
        
    }

}
```

I need to do a POST. Please note that URL to which I am trying to connect is `https` and it requires Basic Auth in order to set a successful connection. However, I am facing below error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at RestClientJson.main(RestClientJson.java:32)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:145)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:461)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 13 more
```

Please suggest to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!! :)

I tried to export certificate of and installed it on my local machine. However still problem pursuits.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the SSL certificates. However, proceeding with the approach mentioned in question was not working out. Hence I went ahead with http-client libraries and below is my working solution.

```
public class RestClientJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, AuthenticationException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
     
        String requestBody = "request JSON body";


        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
         builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
         SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
         Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                    .build();

         PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
         cm.setMaxTotal(100);
         CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                    .setConnectionManager(cm)
                    .build();
   
          HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:port/restService");
          UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("USERNAME", "password");
          request.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request, null));
          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestBody, HTTP.UTF_8);
          request.setEntity(entity);
          request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
          CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
          }
     }
}
```